# ArrayList of LinkedLists reference LinkedLists

Tags: java

I created an arraylist of LinkedLists in the following manner:

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<Card>> list = new ArrayList<>(5);
```

I then needed to add the linkedlists to the arrayList so I did this, which did not seem to work as the ArrayList remained empty

```
for (position = 0; position < list.size(); position++) {
list.add(new LinkedList<Card>());
}
```

So then I manually added linkedLists to the arrayList by giving the LinkedLists references:

```
        LinkedList<Card> temp_list0 = new LinkedList<Card>();
        LinkedList<Card> temp_list1 = new LinkedList<Card>();
        LinkedList<Card> temp_list2 = new LinkedList<Card>();
        LinkedList<Card> temp_list3 = new LinkedList<Card>();
        LinkedList<Card> temp_list4 = new LinkedList<Card>();
        list.add(temp_list0);
        list.add(temp_list1);
        list.add(temp_list2);
        list.add(temp_list3);
        list.add(temp_list4);
```

Finally, though each iteration, i needed to pull out one of the LinkedLists to add something to it and then put it back where it was in the arraylist but by doing this I lose the reference to the LinkedList and thus the information is lost

```
for (position = 0; position < deck.length; position++) {
            scan = (deck[position]).getValue();
            temp_list = list.get(scan);
            temp_list.offer(deck[position]);
            list.add(scan, temp_list);
        }
```

Is there a better way to access to the LinkedLists in the arraylist without losing information, because my way does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your initial `for` loop; `size()` returns the number of elements in the list, not the allocated capacity (if the list implementation even has one). Pull out your `5` into a constant and loop from `0` to the constant instead. Then just use `get()`/`set()` on the `ArrayList` normally.

Note that you don't have to "pull out" and "put back" the contained `LinkedList` objects; you can just call `arrayList.get(linkedListNumber).offer(card);`.

Comment: so when I do arrayList.get(linkedListNumber).offer(card); does it know to put it back in the arraylist?

Comment: @kimos You need to read up on how Java references work. There is no "putting back" involved; you retrieve the `LinkedList` and then perform operations on it (such as inserting an object). The `LinkedList` is still in the `ArrayList` right where it always was until you tell the `ArrayList` to replace or remove it.

Comment: So the objects LinkedLists created will still be in the array even if I did not give their instances a reference ?